# Check if the iframe is "playable"

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I build an app implying music videos, and as you know, some music videos are only available in some countries.
I would like in this cases to load another video for example.

So is there a way to know if an iframe is playable with the youtube iframe API ?

I tried player.getDuration but I got the duration even if the video is not available.

Comment: have you checked the onError event? i think private videos are the same with country policies

Comment: Thank you very much ! That worked.